# Find not finding changed files in untestable conditions

Tags: centos, find

I have a website on a hosting provider, which allows cron jobs to be set up via cpanel.   I have the below cron job set up.   The problem is it is returning 'No Changes' when I know there are changes in /home/myusername/public_html within the last 24 hours.

If I log into cpanel manually to test this job It does show changes because the act of logging in changes a lot of files within my root,  so I can't really test reliably.

I'm trying to exclude the security folder because it comes up access denied in the output so I want a cleaner output.  (Also I think the permission denied message is preventing the 'no changes found' condition from working when it's actually true.

So my question is, is there something wrong with the way I've constructed this cron job/shell command that is preventing it from taking the expected action (find changes in my root folder structure, including `public_html`,  excluding `.security`)

```
findout=$(find  /home/myusername -path /home/myusername/.security -prune -o 
-type f -mtime -1   | egrep '.*') && (printf "Found Changes...\n\n $findout") || 
(printf "No Changes")
```

(the command is all one line but I have split it in the question for better 
readability)

Comment: The exit status of `find` indicates whether it had issues traversing the filesystem, not whether it found anything.

Comment: @Patrick I know that. That's why the egrep is there. If egrep finds nothing then IT has an exit status of zero, which then determines whether to show 'No Changes' or 'Found Changes'

Comment: Please show the complete cron line. Is it in cron.daily or the like or in crontab? Did you check the CRONPATH? Did you try `which find egrep printf`?

Comment: I don't have access to the cron file as it's a hosted package.  I paste the command into a line in cpanel, and include a time to run it.  It runs fine.  It just doesn't give the expected output when there have been changes to the folder structure.  There's nothing wrong with the cron aspect.  The problem is with the command not doing what I thought it would do based on how I've constructed it.

Comment: And do you know, whether egrep exists? I don't have CentOs, and on my machine, the egrep doesn't make a difference. You could try it without - maybe egrep isn't installed?

Comment: "If I log into cpanel manually to test this job It does show changes" - I know egrep works because of this.   It's just odd that the cron doesn't find the changes when it runs at the scheduled time, but does find changes when I set a custom time (a minute or two in the future and then watch for the email)

Comment: @userunknown ... also, the egrep is there as a trick to force a return value true or false, which I can then use to decide whether to display 'changes found' or 'no changes'.. Without the egrep I can't do that off the direct response from find because it only returns false if it had some issue finding (not if it found nothing)

Comment: Well, I don't know cpanel at all. But from Linux support in a big forum, my experience is, that this is a typical symptom of cronjobs, depending on either of 2 reasons in > 90% of the time, one does obviously not apply here (invoking X programs by cron), but the different environment settings, especially CRONPATH, by cron and the user trying the same cmd. on the command line. If I issue 'findout=$(find . -type f -mtime -1 | egreb ".*" 2>/dev/null )  && (printf "Found Changes...\n\n $findout") || (printf "No Changes")` (note egreb instead of egrep),

Comment: I get "No Changes" as a response, too. And I only request to test this for testing, what's going wrong, not as a the general solution to your problem. `findout=$(find . -type f -mtime -5 -name "*.scala" -exec echo '.' ";")  && (printf "Found ${#findout} changes...\n\n") || (printf "Error")` works on my system to count the number of changes, but a) your find needn't have an -exec option (mine is gnu-find) and maybe ${#param} is a bashism to extract the length of a variable.